# Steam api get multiplie game achievments&Schema list with 1 call

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

Hello i will get with 1 call a multiplie game-Achievmentlist from steam because i takes to many time for mulitplie calls.

usually i get the game list from the user and then i call for every game via foreach the xml file.

```
$url5 = http://steamcommunity.com/id/projacore/games/?xml=1';
print $url5;
$data5 = file_get_contents($url5);
$xml5 = simplexml_load_string($data5);
foreach ($xml5->games->children() as $item5){ 

$dasgame = htmlentities($item5->appID);

$url8 = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetSchemaForGame/v0002/?key=' . $steam_api . '&appid=' . $item5->appID . '&l=german&format=xml';
$data8 = file_get_contents($url8);
$xml8 = simplexml_load_string($data8);  


$url11 = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetPlayerAchievements/v0001/?appid=' . $dasgame . '&key=' . $steam_api . '&steamid=' . $item5->appID . '&l=german&format=xml';
$data11 = file_get_contents($url11);
$xml11 = simplexml_load_string($data11);

//and the rest of the code
}
```

it takes so many time because when the user has 50 games it call 50 times data from steam.

now i will ask can i get multiplie Achievments with 1 call?

like this :

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetPlayerAchievements/v0001/?appid=240,400,10&key=' . $steam_api . '&steamid=' . $steamid64 . '&l=german&format=xml
```

thanks ahead

references:

- https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API
- https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/community_data

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not. The Steam API only allows you to query one game (`appid`) at a time.

To get around the 'slowness' that you experience, you may want to populate your web page via AJAX results. This way, the user sees the stats loading one at a time, as your server receives the results back.

A simple work flow:

- User inputs their values as they currently do
- New page loads. On this page, a `div` is created for each `appid` the user has a game for (this should be simple to find with a single API call)
- The page fires off a separate ajax call for each `appid`
- As the results are returned, the `div` associated with the returned results is populated

To the user, it should be obvious that you are retrieving the results, but still presenting them with *some* data before everything has completely returned.

Comment: I'm going to suggest looking at some JQuery tutorials then, focusing specifically on how to dynamically refresh a `div`. A walk through on stackoverflow is well beyond the bounds of what can by typed in an answer. It's a very broad topic depending on what you are doing. To answer your original question though - No, you have to query each game individually to get the achievement statistics. You are unable to query multiple games in a single call.